# External Hardware Info

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, usb-otg

is there is any possibility to check what are the external hardware where connected in computer

Getting the status of each hardware is online or offline

Comment: More context please. External hardware like what? Connected via what? Connected to what - computer of an Android device, as a tag suggests?

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev  external hardware connected to computer via USB port and Serial port

Comment: What does the **android-ndk** tag have to do with your question?

Comment: @AlexCohn android-ndk mean native development kit its full of c and c++ i need to do the above thing in android.. Android supports both java and NDK .. for that purpose only i tagged android-NDK too with java

Comment: @Bucks: do you imply that you actually want to know which external hardware is connected to an Android device via the USB port?

Comment: @AlexCohn printer and Card Reader

Comment: @Bucks: you want to know if a usb printer of card reader is connected to the Android device?

Comment: @AlexCohn  yes .. is it possible ?

Comment: Please rephrase your question to make it less vague, including the new info about "printer and Card Reader". Today it's impossible to understand whether you refer to Android **device** as one of examples of external hardware connected to a **computer**, or you want to understand what peripherals are connected to an Android device. _Note that I added **android** and **usb-otg** tags improve exposure of your question._ I believe that the answer may come from the Java system API of Android, and have nothing to do with **android-ndk**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to take help of linux kernel so I think just execute one simple command that can give you list of devices connected to your device

Here it is

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat /proc/devices");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
```

or you can use [udevinfo](http://www.axllent.org/docs/data_storage/udev_and_external_devices) I dont know in details about it but google is there for you

Comment: it display only what are the Hardware components present in the system

Answer (score 2):

If you have honeycomb or above use the USB Manager Service

```
    UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
    HashMap<String, UsbDevice> devices = manager.getDeviceList();
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to run an external program using `Runtime.exec()`.

There are plenty of examples of how to do this for Windows and Unix, but for Android I suspect another command is required.

Comment: just know i found by using javax.usb we can get list i didnt get any example to getting that hardware list if you know anything abt that ?

Comment: Looking at the web site for `javax.usb` it appears this is best run on Linux (only)

Comment: Umm.. without creating Runtime.exec() method how to get the connected hardware list

Comment: AFAIK, The only hardware you can get is the NetworkInterfaces and the characteristics of the display (like size and colour depth). Java is designed to be system neutral and leave platform specific operations to external programs.